# Perform calculation using lag and dplyr to iterate by row and by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some data like the following data frame:

```
df = data.frame(name=c(rep("Group1",5),rep("Group2",5)),
                mon=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                amt=c(10,NA,NA,NA,NA,15,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                inc=c(.1,.1,.2,.2,.3,.1,.1,.2,.2,.3))

df

     name mon amt inc
1  Group1   1  10 0.1
2  Group1   2  NA 0.1
3  Group1   3  NA 0.2
4  Group1   4  NA 0.2
5  Group1   5  NA 0.3
6  Group2   1  15 0.1
7  Group2   2  NA 0.1
8  Group2   3  NA 0.2
9  Group2   4  NA 0.2
10 Group2   5  NA 0.3
```

There are multiple groups and the first amount column (amt) is populated but the rest in the group are null. I have another column (inc) that is the percent I want to increase the amount field, if it is currently null. When I get to the next group, I want to restart the process.

For example, Group1 mon 2 would be 10*(1+0.1)=11, mon 3 would be a 20% increase on the previously calculated mon 2 value: 11*(1+0.2)=13.2 and so on.

I have been trying to use dplyr and the lag function but I either can't get it work or it's not built for that and I don't know what kind of function would work. I was able to use a loop to iterate over the data frame and get the results I wanted but I was hoping to do it a bit more elegantly to make me a better coder with R.

Below is the loop I built that works currently:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$amt[i] = ifelse(df$mon[i]==1,
         df$amt[i],
         df$amt[i-1]*(1+df$inc[i]))
}

df

     name mon    amt inc
1  Group1   1 10.000 0.1
2  Group1   2 11.000 0.1
3  Group1   3 13.200 0.2
4  Group1   4 15.840 0.2
5  Group1   5 20.592 0.3
6  Group2   1 15.000 0.1
7  Group2   2 16.500 0.1
8  Group2   3 19.800 0.2
9  Group2   4 23.760 0.2
10 Group2   5 30.888 0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're probably running into with [`dplyr::lag()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html) in that it `lag(amt)` will give you the `lag()` of the column as it is, with the `NA` values, rather than a vector which updates as you populate each value iteratively.

You can achieve that behaviour with the [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) function (see below). However, in this case you can just multiply the first `amt` value by the cumulative product by group using [`cumprod()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html).

```r
df |>
    mutate(
        amt = amt[1] * c(1, cumprod(1 + tail(inc, -1))),
        .by = name
    )

#      name mon    amt inc
# 1  Group1   1 10.000 0.1
# 2  Group1   2 11.000 0.1
# 3  Group1   3 13.200 0.2
# 4  Group1   4 15.840 0.2
# 5  Group1   5 20.592 0.3
# 6  Group2   1 15.000 0.1
# 7  Group2   2 16.500 0.1
# 8  Group2   3 19.800 0.2
# 9  Group2   4 23.760 0.2
# 10 Group2   5 30.888 0.3
```

#### Using `Reduce()`

Here is a similar approach to achieve the same result using `Reduce()`. This will be slower but perhaps gives a better sense of what is happening step-by-step.

```r
df |>
    split(~name) |>
    lapply(\(dat)
    transform(dat, amt = Reduce(
        \(x, y) x * (1 + y), tail(dat$inc, -1),
        init = dat$amt[1], accumulate = TRUE
    ))) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _)
```

Comment: a bit more `{dplyr}`-like: `first(amt)`

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! Can you explain why you used amt[1] at the start of the formula? Also, I am not quite sure why you need to use the tail function (I don't really understand it to be honest). Looking at it some more, I am assuming the tail function makes it so the first record is only multiplied by 1?

Comment: @user1723699 Try running `mutate(df, pc_inc = c(1, cumprod(1 + tail(inc, -1))), .by = name)`. This shows you the percent increase that you want to multiply the first value of `amt` by per group, which is what `amt[1]` does. I used `tail(n=-1)` to remove the first value, because you are not calculating `10*0.1`  in the first case - you already know the first value of `amt` and need to populate the rest. See my edit using `Reduce()` - I wouldn't recommend this approach but perhaps this gives a sense of how it works as it calculates the total iteratively.

Comment: @SamR Thank you so much for the explanation and all the help, I really appreciate it. The first approach definitely makes a lot more sense to me than the one using Reduce().